# echoing (creating) an error log file

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, errorlevel

I have the following lines commands:

> if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
>
> ```
>                    set/a error=1
>                    if not exist "error.log" echo. > "error.log"
>                    echo the procedure has got an error >> "error.log" 
>                    echo. >> "error.log
>                   )
> ```

but like this I obtain the message that the file is being processed by another process.

There is maybe another way to create the file if not exists instead of using Echo.

Comment: sorry I correct: the command is :echo the procedure has got an error >> "error.log"

Comment: Probably "the file is being processed by another process."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the file with

```
copy NUL error.log
```

However, I doubt that `echo` is your problem. More likely is that the file already exists and you have it opened in a text editor (or viewer) that locks the file.